# peer dep missing: react@^15.4.2, required by react-native-drawer-menu@0.2.5

Tags: react-native

i am trying to install install @react-navigation/drawer
i am facing below issue 
for that issue i cannot use the drawer navigation in react native
 ERR! peer dep missing: react@^15.4.2, required by react-native-drawer-menu@0.2.5
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-native@^0.41.2, required by react-native-drawer-menu@0.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your version of react to something over v 15.4.2 and react-native to something greater than 041.2